# Fsharpx Async.AwaitObservable does not call cancellation continuation

Tags: asynchronous, f#, system.reactive, f#-async

I'm trying to use Fsharpx' `Async.AwaitObservable` inside an async workflow which is started using `Async.StartWithContinuations`. For some reason, if the cancellation token used to start this workflow is canceled while it is waiting for the observable (but not during other parts of the workflow), the cancellation continuation is never called. However, if I put it inside a `use! __ = Async.OnCancel (interruption)`, then the interruption function does get called. Can someone please clarify why this happens and what the best way is to do this and make sure that one of the continuation functions always gets called?

```
open System
open System.Reactive.Linq
open FSharp.Control.Observable
open System.Threading

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let cancellationCapability = new CancellationTokenSource()

    let tick = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds 1.0)
    let test = async {
        let! __ = Async.AwaitObservable tick
        printfn "Got a thing." }

    Async.StartWithContinuations(test,
        (fun () -> printfn "Finished"),
        (fun exn -> printfn "Error!"),
        (fun exn -> printfn "Canceled!"),
        cancellationCapability.Token)

    Thread.Sleep 100
    printfn "Cancelling..."
    cancellationCapability.Cancel()

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is that FSharpx' definition of AwaitObservable only calls one of the continuation functions if the observable sequence has a next value (or error) before cancellation occurs. It needs to also register a callback with the cancellation token which will call the cancellation continuation and Dispose the resulting CancellationTokenRegistration on the next element in the sequence. Trying to find a way to implement this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the version of Fsharpx on GitHub already contains a fix (not implemented by me). However the current version on NuGet (1.8.41) has not been updated to include this fix. See the change [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/commit/12e93c85ac3755cdb324c9e24cb1b4b332fb1002).

**EDIT 1**:
The code on GitHub also has some issues with Observables with replay semantics. I have fixed this for now like so but hopefully there is a cleaner solution. I will submit a PR after I think about whether there is a way to make it simpler.

```
/// Creates an asynchronous workflow that will be resumed when the 
/// specified observables produces a value. The workflow will return 
/// the value produced by the observable.
static member AwaitObservable(observable : IObservable<'T1>) =
    let removeObj : IDisposable option ref = ref None
    let removeLock = new obj()
    let setRemover r = 
        lock removeLock (fun () -> removeObj := Some r)
    let remove() =
        lock removeLock (fun () ->
            match !removeObj with
            | Some d -> removeObj := None
                        d.Dispose()
            | None   -> ())
    synchronize (fun f ->
    let workflow =
        Async.FromContinuations((fun (cont,econt,ccont) ->
            let rec finish cont value =
                remove()
                f (fun () -> cont value)
            setRemover <|
                observable.Subscribe
                    ({ new IObserver<_> with
                        member x.OnNext(v) = finish cont v
                        member x.OnError(e) = finish econt e
                        member x.OnCompleted() =
                            let msg = "Cancelling the workflow, because the Observable awaited using AwaitObservable has completed."
                            finish ccont (new System.OperationCanceledException(msg)) })
            () ))
    async {
        let! cToken = Async.CancellationToken
        let token : CancellationToken = cToken
        #if NET40
        use registration = token.Register(fun () -> remove())
        #else
        use registration = token.Register((fun _ -> remove()), null)
        #endif
        return! workflow
    })

    static member AwaitObservable(observable : IObservable<'T1>) =
        let synchronize f = 
            let ctx = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current 
            f (fun g ->
                let nctx = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current 
                if ctx <> null && ctx <> nctx then ctx.Post((fun _ -> g()), null)
                else g() )

        let continued = ref false
        let continuedLock = new obj()
        let removeObj : IDisposable option ref = ref None
        let removeLock = new obj()
        let setRemover r = 
            lock removeLock (fun () ->  removeObj := Some r)
        let remove() =
            lock removeLock (fun () ->
                match !removeObj with
                | Some d -> 
                    removeObj := None
                    d.Dispose()
                | None   -> ())
        synchronize (fun f ->
        let workflow =
            Async.FromContinuations((fun (cont,econt,ccont) ->
                let rec finish cont value =
                    remove()
                    f (fun () -> lock continuedLock (fun () ->
                        if not !continued then
                            cont value
                            continued := true))
                let observer = 
                    observable.Subscribe
                        ({ new IObserver<_> with
                            member __.OnNext(v) = finish cont v
                            member __.OnError(e) = finish econt e
                            member __.OnCompleted() =
                                let msg = "Cancelling the workflow, because the Observable awaited using AwaitObservable has completed."
                                finish ccont (new System.OperationCanceledException(msg)) })
                lock continuedLock (fun () -> if not !continued then setRemover observer else observer.Dispose())
                () ))
        async {
            let! cToken = Async.CancellationToken
            let token : CancellationToken = cToken
            use __ = token.Register((fun _ -> remove()), null)
            return! workflow
        })
```

**EDIT 2**:
Neater fix for the hot observable issue...

```
let AwaitObservable(observable : IObservable<'T>) = async {
    let! token = Async.CancellationToken // capture the current cancellation token
    return! Async.FromContinuations(fun (cont, econt, ccont) ->
        // start a new mailbox processor which will await the result
        Agent.Start((fun (mailbox : Agent<Choice<'T, exn, OperationCanceledException>>) ->
            async {
                // register a callback with the cancellation token which posts a cancellation message
                #if NET40
                use __ = token.Register((fun _ ->
                    mailbox.Post (Choice3Of3 (new OperationCanceledException("The opeartion was cancelled.")))))
                #else
                use __ = token.Register((fun _ ->
                    mailbox.Post (Choice3Of3 (new OperationCanceledException("The opeartion was cancelled.")))), null)
                #endif

                // subscribe to the observable: if an error occurs post an error message and post the result otherwise
                use __ = 
                    observable.FirstAsync()
                        .Catch(fun exn -> mailbox.Post(Choice2Of3 exn) ; Observable.Empty())
                        .Subscribe(fun result -> mailbox.Post(Choice1Of3 result))

                // wait for the first of these messages and call the appropriate continuation function
                let! message = mailbox.Receive()
                match message with
                | Choice1Of3 reply -> cont reply
                | Choice2Of3 exn -> econt exn
                | Choice3Of3 exn -> ccont exn })) |> ignore) }
```

Comment: Nice. So the continuation would have been called, but wasn't, because the subscription wasn't disposed properly in the nuget version?

Comment: No, I believe the NuGet version did not register the callback with the cancellation token

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me as well that it's a problem in how AwaitObservable is implemented. Good luck on fixing that.

That said, one workaround that you can use on your client side code is wrapping the AwaitObservable in a Task:

```
async {
    let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
    let! __ = 
        Async.StartAsTask(Async.AwaitObservable tick, cancellationToken = ct)
        |> Async.AwaitTask
    printfn "Got a thing." 
}
```

Not ideal, but works.

Comment: Thanks: this could do the trick for now! I can hide it in a utility library somewhere until someone who knows what they are doing can find proper fix, as I am a bit out of my depth here.